# Professor Layton and the Chamber of Secrets - puzzle series proposal

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, puzzle-series

I'm planning on creating a fan-fiction puzzling story as a Stack Exchange original production, a series of 50-100 questions in which each question contains part of the story, ending in a puzzle to be solved.

Would such a thing be welcomed here? I know some people have created series of 8 to 10 questions like that, but most of them had a thin, specific-to-the-problem story.

Comment: To be specific, the title implies that it'll be a crossover between Harry Potter and Professor Layton; namely that Luke finds himself invited to Hogwarts, and he is accompanied by Professor Layton to solve the mystery of Hogwarts Castle and the Chamber of Secrets.

Comment: And I wouldn't flood the SE with them; at most one puzzle every three or four days.

Comment: There's a lot of precedent for ways in which these types of series can go wrong. How do you see yours being different, generally speaking?

Comment: There is definitely a risk there, I won't deny that. But in my case, as it is a fanfiction revolving around being an adaptation of an existing work, the hard part is creating the puzzles themselves. Additionally, I have experience with writing puzzles as you can see here, and I'm confident that if I can't bring the story to completion, I can at least have written a large volume of high-quality puzzles along the way.

Comment: Also in any case, if I do start working on this, it'll be a month before I post the first puzzle in the series.

Comment: Hmm... I might suggest editing in some details about how you think it'll play out over time, issues you foresee, etc.

Comment: Alright, I'll do that.

Comment: My bit of advice would be to make sure that each puzzle either stands alone or links back to any relevant prior puzzles.  The *story* can continue across all the questions, but we shouldn't have to wade through all of them just to understand the current question.

Comment: @Bobson: To solve that, I'd keep a meta post current with links to all the puzzles.

Comment: You're going to bring the style of your website to PSE? :-o ;-)

Comment: Not quite - it seems that some people don't like my proposal, as indicated by the -1 score on my answer at the moment.

Comment: I love the idea of a puzzle series. I'd vote/suggest against using someone else's super-popular copyrighted/trademarked material without permission to create a large number of posts for the site, though.

Comment: That is true. I had a proposal to create an original story to this effect, but then realized I'd simply be recreating either the *Professor Layton* or the *Puzzle Agent* series with my story layout and decided to turn it into fan fiction instead.

Answer (score 1):

## Game Layout

The story will, in the style of the Professor Layton video games, be a game spanning multiple puzzles. Each puzzle will be worth a set amount of picarats, from 10 for the easiest puzzles to over 100 for the hardest, to be earned upon correctly solving the puzzle.

Everybody will be solving these puzzles and submitting answers together. An incorrect answer to any puzzle will decrease the number of picarats available to earn. Generally the award will stop decreasing after three incorrect guesses, but for some questions it may be more.

### Answering Puzzles

There will be a chatroom dedicated to discussing possible answers. Anything said in there will not count toward a correct or incorrect answer. If you wish to officially submit an answer, post an answer on the thread of the question.

Be careful with your answers, as if you make a mistake, it will also affect everybody else playing the game. Only answers with a score of at least 1 will be considered, so if you make a mistake, do not be afraid that you've done anything bad yet – simply delete your answer and keep thinking.

After each incorrect guess, I will provide a hint, up to three total. These hints will reveal more and more about the puzzle as they keep going.

Comment: Why is this still on Hot Questions? It's not even active anymore.